# Listing Computers in a Network

Tags: android

I have been using the following code to list computers on my Home Network.

```
if (path.equals("smb://")) {
   domains = (new SmbFile(path)).listFiles();
}
```

When I had 2 Windows 10 PCs on my network, this worked fine.

However, since I added a 3rd Windows 10 PC, it throws an exception : "jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.".

If I turn the new computer off, the code works again.

ES File Explorer can access the new Computer from the same Android device.

My question is in 2 parts.

a) Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get the new PC to appear in the list?

or

b) Can I get listfiles() to ignore the PC?  I see you can add an SMBFileNameFilter to the call but can't find much information on what this does and how to use it.

Comment: Just to advise in case it helps others. I was messing about trying to fix this myself. It used to be that when getting a list of available PCs at the "smb://" level, if I used an authorised call (with user name and password) it didn't work. I tried doing that again and now it works! No idea why but hopefully may be of use to others.